# Should it be possible to identify an already-closed question as a duplicate of another question?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

Recently, I found [a closed question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393093/searching-for-online-python-ide?rq=1) that is nearly identical to [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036987/online-ide-for-python), and I don't see any option to identify the first question as a duplicate of the second question. I want to mark this question as a duplicate of the other question, but it appears that there is currently no option to do this, since the question is already closed. In the future, will it be possible to flag already-closed questions as duplicates of existing questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* flag already closed questions as duplicates, but please only do that if the duplicated question shouldn't *also* be closed, like in this case. Generally it's a waste of time to reopen a question just to re-close it as a duplicate of a closed question.

To do it, just use the Other option and explain *clearly* what you want us to do.

Comment: Is it yet possible for a question to be closed for two reasons simulataneously, (e. g., both off-topic and a duplicate of another question)? That's what I would have done in this case, if I had found a way to do this.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: No, it's not. What would happen is it'd be reopened and then closed as a duplicate of whatever post. It's usually better to close something as a duplicate because then you direct them towards an answer and leave a fence post, which is why a flag would be helpful. But I mean, it's still a case-by-case basis.