# Allow users to suggest edits to the duplicate list

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, duplicate-questions

Sometimes I find a question which is closed as a duplicate, but I know a better duplicate to that question. When I find a question which isn't closed for which I know is a duplicate, I can vote or flag to close it as a duplicate, possibly suggesting a different target so both show up. But when the question is already closed as a duplicate, there isn't really any satisfactory way to suggest another target. Here are the options I have, which aren't really satisfactory:

- **Flag for moderator attention so that a moderator can edit the duplicate list**

  This is an option, but I'm not sure a custom flag would be appropriate for something that minor. In any case, it would be better if the community could handle it like they do for questions that aren't closed as duplicates yet.
- **If a user with a gold tag badge or a moderator closed the question as a duplicate, ping them in a comment to suggest the other duplicate**

  This could work if a user with a gold tag badge or a moderator closed the question as a duplicate, but that's not always the case, so this option isn't always available. [Per the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), only those who cast binding close votes can be pinged in comments.
- **Ping a gold-badge holder in chat**

  While this doesn't require a moderator to intervene, not many gold-badge users are active in the site's chat rooms, those who are may not be active in chat at the time the request is posted, causing the request to go unnoticed, and some users prefer not to receive pings regarding duplicate closures.
- **Link to the duplicate in a comment**

  The problem with this is that comments aren't as visible as the duplicate banner, so future users with the same problem aren't really likely to find the target I suggested which has a better answer to their question. This is especially true if the question already has a lot of comments.
- **Answer the duplicate target with a similar answer to the answer to the duplicate question**

  This could be a good option in some cases, but in other cases the answer to the duplicate question isn't an answer to the duplicate target.
- **Flag/vote to close the current duplicate target as a duplicate of the question I found**

  Again, this could work in some cases, but just because there is a third question which is a duplicate of both questions doesn't mean the two questions are necessarily duplicates of each other. In other words, A being a duplicate of B and C doesn't necessarily mean that B is a duplicate of C.

---

Moderators and gold tag badge holders don't have this problem since they can edit the duplicate list, but there is currently no satisfactory way for normal users to suggest another duplicate of a question which is already closed as a duplicate.

I suggest making it possible for users (either any user or users with a certain amount of reputation) to suggest edits to the duplicate list. Just like users who don't have the privilege to edit a post on their own can suggest an edit to that post, users who don't have the privilege to edit the duplicate list on their own should be able to suggest edits to the duplicate list.

I suggest that those suggestions could be treated as suggested edits and be added to the suggested edits queue. Two votes to approve the suggestion would result in the suggestion being approved and two votes to reject would result in the suggestion being rejected. Moderators and gold tag badge holders would have binding votes, and they would also have the possibility to improve or reject and edit.

Reviewing such suggestions could be limited only to certain users in the same way as suggested edits to tag wikis can only be reviewed by 5k users. I suggest requiring 3k reputation to review those suggestions because such users have the privilege to vote to close questions as duplicates, but the required reputation to review those suggestions could be increased if necessary.

If you have any other suggestions on who should be able to review suggested edits to the duplicate list and how the suggestion should be presented to reviewers, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Well, I do support this, but to be honest can't see this happening. The "edit duplicates list" was added as some kind of bonus already, hard to believe they'll spend even more time on this. Pinging gold hammer with a suggestion is good enough for the rare cases where it's needed.

Comment: It's easiest to simply [use a comment to suggest a similar or duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188478/282094); the proposed question will appear in the right column under the "Linked" list - see: ➚