# How should I recommend a different duplicate target?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

When I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58277445/1092820) I recommended closing it as a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/438939/1092820), but I soon noticed that the question was not quite similar enough, and none of the answers really answer it.

Very soon after, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922092/1092820) in search of a better duplicate target. But a gold badger had already gone through and marked the question as a duplicate of my original nomination while I was looking for the later one.

I tried @ing the gold badger but they didn't comment so I suppose that doesn't ping their notifications.

So, what's the appropriate course of action here? Should I nominate it for reopening because the duplicate target isn't valid as such? Should I flag it for moderator attention with the proper duplicate question? Should I look for a comment from the gold badger so I can @ them back to the post in question?

Comment: Post a comment under the question with the better dupe target, and try to get a gold badge holder to edit the dupe-target section. (Gold badgers and moderators can do that.) If you can't get a gold badger in a timely manner, flag for moderator attention. Ordinarily, a flag would be the way to go IMO, but currently the mods here are under heavy load, so we should try not to add to that load if we can avoid it. Appendix: I just noticed it's on SO, not here, so just flag it.

Comment: Gold badge holders can be [pinged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/377968) this way: "The moderator or gold badge holder who closed or reopened the question, provided they were the only one to do so."

Comment: @AnneDaunted Thanks for the info. As I understand it, gold badger wasn't the only one involved in the closing (as it was closed before I could withdraw my suggestion, I'm also involved) so this doesn't work...

Comment: Taking it to MSO generally works.

Comment: @AnneDaunted In this case, as another user was involved in the closure, the hammer-er can't be replied to in the comments.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That's exactly what the quote says.

Comment: A list of methods is offered in this FR question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306326/282094 - it also suggests some of the benefits and drawbacks of each possible method, without coming to a definitive conclusion as to 'which is best'.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't believe it is a duplicate, the policy is fairly clear. It's a two-part test:

- Do the questions themselves say very nearly the same thing?
- Does the alleged duplicate question have an adequate answer?